Wix REST API: Create a draft post using html directly in content
When using the WIX Rest API to create a draft post I am sending the following in the request:
post_params = {
    draftPost : {
        memberId: member_id,
        title: 'My New Post',
        richContent: {
            nodes: [{
                type: "HTML",
                id: "",
                nodes: [],
                htmlData: {
                    containerData: {},
                    source: "HTML",
                    html: html_content
                }
            }],
        }
    },
    published:false,
};

This will embed my html in a data container in the blog post rather than implement the html directly (as other platforms like WordPress or Shopify do when posting a blog with their API).

Is there a way to implement my HTML directly when creating a draft post via the Wix REST API? Or a way to implement rich text directly? The docs describe many different nodes that one can utilize but I don't see any that allow me to simply implement my existing html directly into a draft blog. Am I missing something?
